# How to view a variable's content in Ionic 2 UI page

Tags: html, ionic2

I am working on Ionic 2 with firebase. I have written the code for it. I can see the value on the console. But, how can I get it on HTML page.

In HTML `{{ fullname }}` did not work.

```
aa(){
    return this.data.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        var fullname = snapshot.val().fullname;
        console.log(fullname);
        return fullname;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The variable fullname getting created at `var fullname = snapshot.val().fullname;` is a scoped variable. It's scope ends after the execution of the `aa()` method.

You need to declare this in the class than a particular method. This class is the class where your `@component` is defined.

Code:

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'page.html'
})
export class Page {
    fullname;

    constructor(){}

    aa(){
        return this.data.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
            this.fullname = snapshot.val().fullname;
            console.log(this.fullname);
            return this.fullname;
        });
    }
}
```

Also, in your html, use it as `{{fullname}}`.